# How do you imbed a jQuery into an html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I was trying to add a tic tac toe game which I had previously written in python into my HTML page. How should I do that? Should I convert it into jQuery and then add it into my HTML page?

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tic tac toe sounds like a web app that would be easiest to implement with css and Javascript. Jquery is a Javascript framework, it might be beneficial to rely on only Javascript, not a framework until you become more familiar with both of them.

To add jquery to an html file, you need to add the jquery file you downloaded within script tags.

```
<script src="/downloaded_jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

save your codes to file with extention of `.js` and then your can add your file to html page in `<script></script>`

```
<head>
<script src="/pathtojsfile/your-jquery-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

it help to include your file to html
if you want to write more codes to initialize js feel free to add it between this tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//your codes here
</script>
```